# interfaces to fix inheritence mess?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, refactoring

I'm working on a project with the following (very simplified) structure:

```
BaseClass

SubClassA : BaseClass
SubClassB : BaseClass
```

There is a UI (with a lot of logic) which uses `SubClassA`, and then saves it to another component which takes `BaseClass` as a parameter **but** immediately casts the argument to `SubClassB`.  This fails as the UI is passing in `SubClassA`.

UI:

```
MyComponent.Save(subClassA)

Component:
Save(BaseClass baseClass)
{
SubClassB subClassB = (SubClassB)baseClass;
```

...

the current implementation creates an instance of SubClassB in the UI and pass that across - but it leads to lots of code such as

```
SubClassB.Property1 = SubClassA.Property1a
```

I'm contemplating creating a common interface which the 2 sub classes would implement.  It would be a lot of work but slowly I think I could flatten the current very deep hierarchy.  Reworking either the UI or the component to use the other sub type would be just as much work as the structures are different (though many fields map).  Is the interface approach the right way to go?  I feel there might be something I'm missing.

Comment: I don't see what interface would come to help here... Why don't you fix the save method? It should take a SubClassB as param or should support properly BaseClass.

Comment: @LightStriker - if I updated the save to take a SubClassB, I'd still have the issue of casting from the UI to a subclassB instance.  Unfortunately the base class doesn't have much of the detail in the sub classes, my thinking is an interface would be a starting point to a more coherent interaction across multiple components (the inheritance is a bit of a mess...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SubclassA` and `SubclassB` are related only by their ability to `Save`, then yes, `BaseClass` would be better as an interface that both sub-classes implement.

It won't solve your immediate problem straight away: the component casting from base class to (the wrong) derived class. It looks like there could be several levels of refactoring to do here. Patching up the code so that the component casting to a `SubclassA` by making one for it to use is wasteful, I think. Changing the component so it can operate on a single common type would be a big win there.

Flattening a deep hierarchy would bring lots of other benefits, too - like making it simpler. If there end up being a few interfaces that they all implement, that's not necessarily a bad thing. Beware of lots of interface types hunting in packs, however.

In short, reworking both the UI and the component - and any other code, too - to work in terms of just a small number of interfaces, with no knowledge of the implementing classes, will pay dividends.

Comment: it's not so much the ability to save that relates the classes, it's their properties (they are very similar) - I agree flattening and refactoring would be a big win.  Out of curiosity, can you explain 'interface types hunting in packs'?

Comment: @NDJ - it can be tempting to create lots of very small interfaces providing fine-grained functionality (like "ISave", "ILoad" - you get the idea), instead of capturing real abstractions. I guess what I meant was, if you find yourself needing to implement lots of interfaces, and there is a common "pack" you need for several implementing classes, it's often an indicator that there's a higher level abstraction to be found.

Answer (score 2):

From a *consumer* standpoint, interfaces can do almost everything that abstract classes can do (the main exceptions being that a class can expose a field as a byref, while interfaces have no means of doing so, and that static members associated with a class can be grouped under the class name, static members related to an interface must be grouped under a different name).  Except in those rare cases where it's necessary to expose a field as a byref, the primary advantage of an abstract class comes on the side of the implementation.  All of the functionality associated with an interface must be provided separately in every class which implements it, even when such functionality is common to 99% of the classes which implement it.  By contrast, if 99% of the concrete classes derived from an abstract class will implement a particular method the same way, it's possible for the abstract class to define that method once and let derived classes inherit it without having to pay it any heed whatsoever.  Such an advantage can be nice, but there's a major catch: a class can only inherit functionality from one other class.  Since interfaces don't include any functionality, they can be inherited from any number of other classes.

When one is defining an abstract class, I would suggest that one should in many cases also define an interface which includes the same public functionality (which the abstract class should implement), and avoid using variables or parameters of the abstract class type.  This will allow implementations which can inherit from the abstract class to achieve the ease-of-implementation benefits that would come from doing so, but will also make it possible to define implementations which inherit from something else.  Writing an implementation which inherits from some other type would be more work, but if code never uses the abstract-class type in variable, field, or parameter declarations, code which uses derivatives of the abstract class would work just as well with interface implementations that don't.

Comment: +1 - but noting also that implementing interfaces doesn't "use up" your single-inheritance quota

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a `Save()` `virtual` within the base class - it seems like a better option. That way, if you have any common save functionality, you can use it and also give it other forms in derived classes - known as `polymorphism`.

```
class BaseClass
{
  public virtual void Save()
  {
    //Use this keyword
  }
}
class B : BaseClass
{
  public override void Save()
  {
    base.Save();
  } 
}
```